# Menubar Calculator for OS X?

Tags: macos, software-rec, calculator

Is there a good calculator that I can run from the menubar?

I know that I can type calculations into Spotlight but I'd like something a bit more full-featured. Also, Spotlight frequently has a delay when I type.

Comment: If you use a launcher (Quicksilver, Launchbar, Alfred), it might already have that same feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried Menulator in the past. It works but interface is bit dated and confusing. Mac App Store has few more options.

Menulator: [http://web.mit.edu/eranki/www/menulator/ [Free Circa 2002]](http://web.mit.edu/eranki/www/menulator/)

Search for **"menu calculator"** in the Mac App Store you will get following apps

1. CalcuBar:  http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id429717936?mt=12
2. CalcMenu:  itunes.apple.com/us/app/id425338970?mt=12
3. Pocket Calculator: itunes.apple.com/us/app/id422264271?mt=12